# When checking out a branch, files get deleted and are shown in git status as deleted

Tags: git

so I updated git to the latest version (2.29.2.windows.2) and also Visual Studio to version 16.8.1 (both may not be related to the bug).

When I checkout from branch `setup/version1_0` to `develop`, there are suddenly files removed.
They are shown when using `git status` as changes not staged for commit after changing the branch.
This only happens when changing from this exact branch: `setup/version1_0`.
These files are **not** deleted in the setup branch, nor are they deleted in any other branch.

Answer (score 0):

We found an issue with the setup branch. There is one commit in which all these files were shown as "Added" - even though they never were removed and existed all along.

So there is the issue, but there is no fix it seems. Interactive Rebasing is no option since this commit has a lot of other files as well. Also no idea how/when this occurs.